# When roasting or sauteeing vegetables, does it matter if it was fresh, canned or frozen?

Tags: substitutions

I am duplicating a recipe I used from Homechef, using store bought ingredients.

One thing I often see is that canned or frozen vegetables (sometimes in streamable bags) are cheaper then fresh, but when originally cooking them they are always fresh.

Would it be possible to use frozen or canned products instead of fresh when roasting or sauteeing them. Would there be any significant change in taste or anything?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  You'll find that we can help you a lot better if you post a link to the recipe you're making, a similar recipe, or at least name and describe it.  As posted, your question is very general and will result in very general answers that maybe don't apply.  For more information, see How To Ask: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Canned products are by definition cooked, so the results will be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would change would be the taste & texture.

Pulses [bean/chickpeas etc] are virtually the same canned as cooked from dried. These are the usual two methods. Fresh isn't really an option to most people, so dried or canned are the accepted sources.
Tomatoes are used canned so often they have become almost a "food type" of their own. To many people, Italian food almost depends on the canned tomato.
Almost nothing else I can think of off the top of my head can be canned without totally changing the flavour & texture for the worse. Canned food is already cooked, so sautéing won't really be necessary.

Frozen has an even smaller window. Peas will freeze & be as good if not better than fresh. Crushed garlic is OK. Almost nothing else works. Carrots, cauliflower, broccoli, potatoes & the like are all <s>*revolting*</s> ...ermm...  <s>*inedible*</s> ...err... not as good as fresh.

Really, if you want the full experience, as designed by the recipe author, there is no substitute for fresh vegetables.
Supermarkets will often do small bags of fresh, ready-prepared vegetables, single variety or useful mixes. Though pound for pound they are more expensive than peeling & chopping yourself, they can sometimes prove more economical as you simply don't have to buy a full quantity of items you really only need one each of.